# FormatCurrency in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, excel-2011, vba

Below is some code I extracted from a Youtube tutorial using Excel 2010.  When I try to run this on Excel 2011 for the Mac, the currency outputs are all integers. Does FormatCurrency() work differently in this version of Excel?  Or have I just screwed up something (again)?  Thanks for any help.

Best,
Tony Lima

```
Option Explicit
' Tony Lima, July 23, 2014

Const SCOOPPRICE As Double = 0.75
Const TIPPERCENT As Double = 0.15

' ****************************************
' Ice cream store order and print receipt
' *****************************************

Private Sub btnOrder_Click()
    Dim numScoops As Integer
    Dim scoopCost As Double
    Dim tipAmount As Double
    Dim totalCost As Double

    '*** get the number of scoops ordered
    numScoops = CInt(txtScoops.Text)
    '*** calculate cost of ice cream and tip amount
    scoopCost = numScoops * SCOOPPRICE
    tipAmount = scoopCost * TIPPERCENT
    '*** add the two to get the total cost
    totalCost = scoopCost + tipAmount

    '*** print receipt
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("Thanks for your order!")
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("")
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("You ordered " & CStr(numScoops) & " scoops of ice cream")
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("Cost of ice cream " & FormatCurrency(scoopCost, 2))
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("Tip (thank you) " & FormatCurrency(tipAmount, 2))
    lstReceipt.AddItem ("Total cost " & FormatCurrency(totalCost, 2))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works fine in Excel 2010 on Windows 7 pc. Try using the immediate window in the VBE and pepper some debug.print statements in to see what's going on.

```
Debug.print FormatCurrency(scoopCost,2) for example...
```

Just thought you should know that it does work.

Comment: I kind of figured it was a 2011 issue.  Thanks for the tip -- I'll try it later today and report the results.

Comment: It's something in the code.  FormatCurrency(200.00, 2) returns $200.00 in the immediate window.  Same result using 200 instead of 200.00.  If I figure out what's going on I'll post here.

Comment: After a closer look, it's not $200.00, but $200 00. Bug in FormatCurrency() fwiw.

Comment: In Excel 2011 you need to use Format(<number>, "Currency") - works for FormatPercent, too.

Comment: Cool! That's good to know.  Also, kinda disturbing that MS changes something like that from version to version/platform to platform... You would think they would be more consistent. "It's not a bug... _it's a feature_"